# Laravel View not Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am returning a view in a laravel app Here is the route

```
Route::get('roles', 'CreateList@create');
```

and then in the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CreateList extends Controller
{
    function create(){

        $roles = DB::table('sec_role')->get();
        return view('roles.blade.php', compact('role_id', 'name'));

    }
}
```

Finally I do have a roles.blade.php in my Resources/views folder
but when I go to the route I get the

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [roles.blade.php] not found.
```

error

I've alredy tried clear and config the cache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use full file name:

```
 return view('roles', compact('role_id', 'name'));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#view-responses

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the full file name:

```
 return view('roles', compact('role_id', 'name'));
```

If the view is inside any folder,You have to use the folder name to access the view.
Eg,If folder name is user,

```
     return view('user.roles', compact('role_id', 'name'));
```